# Kivy: How to add padding to a Text Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Just a simple problem here - I would like to add some 'padding' to my text input box so as to align it with a label above it: see [here](https://pasteboard.co/fx1Sa6ki7.png)

Here are the relevant sections of my .kv file:

```
<InstructionsLabel>:
    font_size: 24
    size_hint_y: None
    color: 0.447, 0.094, 0.737, 1
    text_size: root.width, None
    size: self.texture_size
    padding_x: 20

<LengthExactScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        DirectionButton:
            text: "Back"
            pos_hint: {'left': 1, 'top': 1}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                root.manager.current = "tool_screen"
        DirectionButton:
            text: "Done"
            pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'top': 1}
            on_press: root.compute_orders(root.itemList, int(len_exact_input.text))
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.86}
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: "vertical"
            InstructionsLabel:
                text: "Enter the number of items you want to order"
            TextInput:
                id: len_exact_input
                size_hint: None, None
                width: 300
                height: 35
                multiline: False
                hint_text: ""
```

Comment: You need to provide a value to size_hint:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TextInput has also a padding property.

Change this to match the padding on your label

```
TextInput:
    padding_x:[20,0]
```

Here is a sample App I wrote to see that adopted from your code. Unfortunately, your code has several issues and it was easier to do it like that
[image]

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<rootwi>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        font_size: 24
        text: 'iuqwdouqwdoqdwpqwpow'
        color: 0.447, 0.094, 0.737, 1
        text_size: root.width, None
        size: self.texture_size
        padding_x: 20
    TextInput:
        padding_x:[20,0]
""")
class rootwi(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootwi()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: padding_x and padding_y are depcrecated, you should use padding instead. https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html

Answer (score 0):

Padding is internal to the TextInput and will only serve to make it larger - it won't help with aligning it to the text in a Label that has padding. Unfortunately Kivy has no concept of "margins", so the easiest way you can get the TextInput's box to align with a padded Label is to wrap it in a container that has a transparent background, and set the padding on that widget instead - effectively faking a margin. For example:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "Hello World!"
        padding: dp(20), dp(10)
    BoxLayout:
        padding: dp(20), dp(10)
        TextInput:
            text: "Hello to you too!"
```

While frequently annoying, this behaviour makes perfect sense; the Label is a box with padding and a background, and just like the TextInput the Label grows when you add padding - it's just that you don't notice this since unlike the TextInput the Label doesn't have a background *colour*.

Answer (score -3):

you can also do some research @ [kivy text input](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html). that should give you all the information you need and more.