# Kivymd MDLabel padding or margin

Tags: python, design-patterns, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I hope you are doing great.
I would like to keep space between the text in MDLabel and the edges of the screen any help ideas?
this is my code for the first page .kv
MDScreen:
name:"splash"
MDFloatLayout:
md_bg_color: (255/255, 250/255, 245/255, 1)
Image:
source:"assets/1.png"
size_hint:.50,.50
pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.8}

```
        MDLabel:
            text:"the Vine Reco App"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.63}
            halign:"center"
            theme_text_color:"Custom"
            text_color: (106/255, 90/255, 200/255, 1)
            font_size:"28sp"
            font_name:"Lemonada"
        MDLabel:
            text:"Recognizing the Type of the vine based on the image of list leaves"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.4}
            halign:"center"
            theme_text_color:"Custom"
            text_color: (5/255, 215/255, 80/255, 1)
            font_size:"22sp"
        MDRaisedButton:
            text:"Get Started"
            font_name: 'Fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf'
            font_size:35
            markup: True
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.12}
            md_bg_color:(140/255, 220/255, 150/255, 1)
            text_color: (22/255, 160/255, 133/255, 1)
```

the image i will attached shows where i need spaces [image: my first page]

Comment: `MDLabel` has an attribute `padding`, a list of two values. Try setting this.

Comment: padding: ('10dp', '8dp', '5dp', '1dp')

"
kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\ymarmoud\Desktop\python\start\firstUse.kv", line 25:
 ...
      23:            text_color: (5/255, 215/255, 80/255, 1)
      24:            font_size:"22sp"
 >>   25:            padding: ('10dp', '8dp', '5dp', '1dp')
      26:        MDRaisedButton:
      27:            text:"Get Started"
 ...
 ValueError: MDLabel.padding value length is immutable
   File "C:\Users\ymarmoud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 704, in _apply_rul......

Comment: i got error as you see

Comment: Please read the comment carefully.

Comment: i did padding ('10dp', '10dp') nothing change
i did padding (10, 10) nothing change
i did padding ('10sp', '10sp') nothing change

Comment: Setting it in `kvlang` as `padding: dp(10), dp(10)` should've worked as [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.padding) describes.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
MDLabel:
            text:"Recognizing the Type of the vine based on the image of list leaves"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.4}
            halign:"center"
            theme_text_color:"Custom"
            text_color: (5/255, 215/255, 80/255, 1)
            font_size:"22sp"
            padding:[40,0]
```

Comment: from here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403466/kivy-how-to-add-padding-to-a-text-input